# @GuardedBy annotation with java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock

Tags: java, concurrency, annotations, static-analysis, findbugs

What is a proper/preferred way to annotate fields that are protected with a `ReadWriteLock` so that tools like FindBugs can leverage the annotation? Should the name of the `ReadWriteLock` simply be written in the `@GuardedBy` annotation. Is there ever a reason to write the name of just the read lock, or just the write lock, in the `@GuardedBy` annotation? Does FindBugs, or other tools, even support `ReadWriteLock` in `@GuardedBy`?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

At the time of this writing, `@GuardedBy` [isn't fully implemented by Findbugs](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=1872999&group_id=96405&atid=614696), and is mostly just for documentation. (It is *partially* implemented.)

I always use `@GuardedBy("readwritelock")` or the object that I use to `synchronize`.

For example of the latter:

```
class Example {
    private Object lock = new Object();

    @GuardedBy("lock")
    private Stuff innards = ...;

    public void work() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            workWith(innards.goop());
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just a quick note, I don't know the state of the FindBugs art (hence I asked this question! :), but the link that mentions that the annotation might not be implemented appears to be four years old.

Comment: That project is very active, judging by the activity on the linked-to bug-tracker.

Comment: You mean the FindBugs project? Oh sure, it's alive and well. I meant the specific statement from four years ago that the GuardedBy annotation might not be implemented. I'm saying that the most recent FindBugs code might implemented it. Sorry if I misread/misunderstood  something.

Comment: Likewise, but the link is still to their bug tracker. If it were _my_ bug tracker, I would have searched for @guardedby when I did any updates to it. But then again, it isn't my bug tracker

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that the GuardedBy annotation does not work in FindBugs anymore. I stumbled upon this problem (FindBugs ignoring obvious bugs) and found this open ticket: http://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/765/

Answer (score 1):

Find bugs supports the following annotations:

```
net.jcip.annotations.GuardedBy
net.jcip.annotations.Immutable
net.jcip.annotations.NotThreadSafe
net.jcip.annotations.ThreadSafe
```

Usage of these GuardedBy annotation should be as follows:

```
@ThreadSafe  
public class Queue<E> implements java.util.Queue<E>  
{  
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue readWriteLock;  

    @GuardedBy( value="readWriteLock" )  
    public boolean offer(E o)  
    {  
        return queue.offer( o ); 
    }  

}
```

Comment: These annotations are also captured in JSR305. They can be seen in this reference implementation: http://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/concurrent/

Comment: The name of the lock can be written more compactly like this: @GuardedBy("readWriteLock") -- the "value=" portion isn't explicitly required.

Comment: My question isn't really about basic usage. I'm trying to figure out whether a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReadWriteLock, which contains both a read lock and a write lock should be referred to in a @GuardedBy annotation as the whole ReadWriteLock, or by the individual read and write locks. And whether any of this is effective.

Comment: @GregMattes - If one or the other, specify the individual read/write lock. Otherwise, specify the master lock.